# Is it possible to make div with class="input-group" look the same as class="form-group"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In order to get my select list working as an input I have had to use `<div class="input-group">`, however it is not displaying that same way as my other `<div class="form-group">`'s.

Below is example code and a screen shot of the positional difference.

[image: Positional Difference]

```
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Actual Start Date:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input name="ActStartDate" type="date" class="form-control" id="ActStartDate" placeholder="Actual Start Date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["AStDate"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Actual End Date:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input name="ActEndDate" type="date" class="form-control" id="ActEndDate" placeholder="Actual End Date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["AEnDate"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Priority:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                  <select name="PPriority" class="selectpicker form-control" id="PPriority" data-live-search="true">
                    <optgroup>
                    <?php echo "<option value=" .$_SESSION["Priority"]. " selected disabled >" .$_SESSION["Priority"]. "</option>"?>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="-----------">
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    </optgroup>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Priority:</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <select name="PPriority" class="selectpicker form-control" id="PPriority" data-live-search="true">
                <optgroup>
                <?php echo "<option value=" .$_SESSION["Priority"]. " selected disabled >" .$_SESSION["Priority"]. "</option>"?>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="-----------">
                <option>3</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>1</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

just replace the div class with form-group it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your bootstrap CSS, look for the `input-group` element, and remove the following css code: `display: table;`. It will work fine.